# Chrome Source view interpretting JS block comments incorrectly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome is currently displaying the bulk of the code in our JS files as commented out in the source view. This first section of code is managed, we don't have direct control of it. It's also fairly static, and hasn't changed in a long time. Our application code itself follows this managed code, and as a result is displayed commented out.

That said, as of a day or two ago, I started seeing this issue when I try to debug our application.

[image: Chrome Source view]

As you can see, the block comments are not terminating with the */ as expected. However while RUNNING the code, it is properly executed, as indicated by the paused execution on line 4.

I can add a /* */ at the top of a file and the code in that file will appear in source view correctly, and I can debug.

The bottom line is I can no longer debug efficiently.

My co-workers are not experiencing this issue, even on the same server, which makes it even weirder. I'm running the most up to date Chrome (Version 116.0.5845.111 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and have disabled all extensions.

For comparison, here's the same code in FF:

[image]

Update: Adding in the complete first few lines of the file just in case that helps.

```
var App = App || {}; App.Widgets = App.Widgets || {}; App.Widgets['aaa-bbb-ccc-portlet'] =
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
```

Comment: That isn't a block comment. A comment that starts with `/*` ends with the next `*/`. So `/******/` is a self-ending comment.

Comment: @Barmar That’s what OP said…

Comment: Now I understand, they're just talking about how it's color-coded in the source code viewer.

Comment: I think there' was a Chrome update a few days ago, maybe this is a bug there.

Comment: Hi Chrome DevTools team member here, Is it possible for you to share the file url and the version of Chrome you are using?

Comment: Hi @Jecfish, Looks like Version 116.0.5845.141 (Official Build) (64-bit), so I've updated at least once since this post went up. Still the same issue. I can't share a URL publicly unfortunately. I'll update the main post with the first few lines of the file though, in case anything looks like it could cause an issue. It's pretty standard stuff though.